# How to handle Unsupported operand types in mypy when type should be clear?

Tags: python, mypy

Consider the following toy example.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, optional_arg: float | None = None) -> None:
        self.optional_arg = optional_arg

        self._parse_args()

    def _parse_args(self) -> None:
        if self.optional_arg is None:
            self.optional_arg = 0.5

    def multiply(self) -> float:
        # mypy is complaining with the below statement:
        # error: Unsupported operand types for * ("float" and "None")  [operator]
        # Right operand is of type "Optional[float]"
        return 0.5 * self.optional_arg
```

After instantiating this class with `optional_arg=None`, it should be clear that `self.optional_arg` will be set to a `float` due to the `_parse_args` method.

In my view, it should be clear that when calling the method `multiply`, it will return a `float`. However, `mypy` is still complaining that `self.optional_arg` might be `None`.

What is a pythonic way to tell `mypy` that `self.optional_arg` can't possibly be `None`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.optional_arg` doesn't have to be the value set by `_parse_args`. Someone might do

```
x = MyClass()
x.optional_arg = None
x.multiply()
```

and as far as mypy is concerned, that's a valid way to use `MyClass`.

Alternatively, someone might override `_parse_args`:

```
class Subclass(MyClass):
    def _parse_args(self) -> None:
        pass

Subclass().multiply()
```

and as far as mypy is concerned, that's legal too.

If you want mypy to treat `self.optional_arg` as never `None`, you shouldn't set it to a value that could be `None` in the first place. You can use a float as the default in the first place:

```
class MyClass:
    optional_arg: float
    def __init__(self, optional_arg: float = 0.5) -> None:
        self.optional_arg = optional_arg
    ...
```

or do your `None` handling before you set the attribute:

```
class MyClass:
    optional_arg: float
    def __init__(self, optional_arg: float | None = None) -> None:
        self.optional_arg = optional_arg if optional_arg is not None else 0.5
    ...
```

Comment: Or do `def __init__(self, optional_arg: float = 0.5) -> None:` and leave out `_parse_args` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

**user2357112** answer is great and you should go for it in that case.
However not everytime it's easy to have proper typing (excecially working with legacy code). In such case you can use [type narrowing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_narrowing.html).

```
     def multiply(self) -> float:
        assert isinstance(self.optional_arg, float)
        return 0.5 * self.optional_arg
```

Comment: That's also a very helpful tip! Awesome.